# fuelphp profiler doesn't work on Windows

Tags: fuelphp

I am trying to enable fuelphp profiler. According to their documents [here](http://fuelphp.com/docs/general/profiling.html) I just have to

```
'profiling'  => true,
```

However it is not working on Windows (any browser), but when I tried it on Mac its working, I used the same code, config, same version of PHP and fuelphp, etc.

I am using fuelphp version 1.5 and PHP version 5.6.

Fuelphp profiler really helps a lot, any clue how to fix this on windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found a solution to this problem!!! i am using fuelphp version 1.5
on \core\vendor\phpquickprofiler\display.php on function loadCSS()

from

```
sheet.innerHTML = '$css';
```

to

```
sheet.innerHTML = `$css`;
```

Hope this will help us all. You may find the solution wierd, I find it wierd too! I just got a hint, saw some logs about 'sheet.innerHTML' on the console of firebug. I tried double quotes etc, but this one worked.